# Why getting The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax error in react?

Tags: javascript, deployment, hosting, netlify, website-deployment

I have a react application which I want to deploy on netlify.However Im getting the following error:

```
 The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to find the npm module for what you're trying to import and include if via

`import exampleJS from '@exampleJS/exampleJS';`